# Another "Object not set to the instance of an object" Error

Tags: c#, object, itext, pdfstamper

I have been struggling with this error for a few days now. Hopefully you can see what I cannot and help point me in the right direction.

```cs
private void FillFormChg()
{
    pdfTemplate = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "Slip.pdf");
    newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "SlipTemp.pdf");

    try
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        
        if (pdfTemplate == null && newFile == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't find Templates!");
            return;
        }
        
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
        pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
    }
}
```

I have checked for null, and made sure that the templates are there and readable, but I still get the error on the PdfStamper line. Thank you in advance for your insight!

Comment: What line does the exception occur on?

Comment: PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

Comment: Consider looking at the stack trace of the error to determine details. If it is not clear to you, consider posting it here.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I understand the reason behind the error but not what is causing it.

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?

Comment: Stack Trace-  System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=itextsharp
  StackTrace:
   at iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance()

Comment: ` System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=itextsharp
  StackTrace:
   at iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance()
`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full message, including **all** entries in the stack trace

Comment: So how do capture all entries of the stack trace?

Comment: For future reference, I discovered that although I had added iTextSharp through NuGet, I failed to create a reference to it.... Once I had the reference it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (pdfTemplate == null && newFile == null)
```

This should probably be an || and not an &&.  If one of those files is null, but not both, then it would crash later if pdfTemplate was null and newFile was not.

Comment: Also: `PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);` uses `pdfTemplate` before the check.

Comment: Now that makes sense to me. I will make changes and give it a go. Thank you Fildor!

Comment: Same error, after moving the PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate); past the template null check.

Comment: @s.d.c321 I actually doubt moving down that line will remedy the error, despite being "more correct". I am not sure what happens if the argument to `new PdfReader` is not a null string but the file _does not exist_ ...

Comment: @Fildor I have another method the creates the templates before this method is called. I know they exist in the right location and are readable.

Comment: Hm, then I honestly do not know what else _could_ be null in that line. I'd step it through in the debugger and check any variables on the way.